# Is it okay to answer a question with a solution that was not possible when the question was asked?

Tags: discussion

Let me give an example:

I asked this question: [Disable "Close all incognito tabs" notification?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/148684/306191). 
To which I gave [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216810/306191).

Would it be okay to give this answer considering it was not possible to use this solution when this question was asked?

In the answer, I also said that the solution may not work with some devices, which makes me think it is okay to do so, but still...

Comment: I upvoted the answer mainly because you gave another solution and explained that " previously given options may deactivate important notifications you may not want to miss".

Answer (score 5):

My own policy to address old questions is this:

Answer the question as long as I'm not restricted by OS release or some applications' release. So let's say if a question is dependent on Android 5.0 and my solution is for Android 6.0 or above, I tend to not address that question because neither OP nor future audience with the same version-specific issue would be helped by that solution per se, though there are exceptions too, such as, say "A new update to XYZ software solved the problem", so this seems fine as a solution in some cases.

In such cases, I  also try to mention the Android version, and other relevant software's version if needed be, I tested my solution upon so as to prevent any confusion for OP or future audience to understand or apply the solution.

Note that mentioning of Android version in a question doesn't necessarily make the problem related to that. I have to understand the problem first and see whether Android version or some other software version has any bearing on the problem at all.

In your case, I see that OP didn't limit the question to any specific Chrome or Android version release, so your solution seems  fine to me.